# How do I get the generated proxy class of a WCF service to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

Is it possible to have the proxy classes that are generated when setting a service reference implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

In this case it's a silverlight app referencing a WCF service?

Update:

The `SlSvcUtil.exe` commandline utility is part of the silverlight SDK installed {Program Files}\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Tools will generate the classes with an `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation.

I'll leave this question up, as I live in hope that someone will say this is possible from Visual Studio without haing to launch an external tool.

Comment: After further investigation it seems that if returning an EntityObject from EF4 I get INotifyPropertyChanged -- but the question remains, how to do this with POCO, and not EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxy classes do not implement that interface, only DataContracts do. If you open .svcmap file generated by adding service reference in XML viewer you can change EnableDataBinding element to true and update service reference from VS. I thought that true is default value and you have to manually changed it if you don't want to use INotifyPropertyChanged. What is so specific in your service?